# About number of algebra of dimension 2 over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I got stuck in this exercise. I would be so grateful if anyone can give me a hint for it. Thanks a lot

> Let k be a field, A a k-algebra of dimension 2. Choose $t \in A, t \notin k \subset A$. Then $A$ is generated by $1$ and $t$ and so there is an isomorphism of algebras $k[x]/(x^2+ax+b) \cong A$ for some $a, b \in k$. Which of the following are true:
>
> 1. if $k = \mathbb{Q}$, there are infinitely many non-isomorphic possibility for $A$
> 2. if $k = \mathbb{F_p}$, there are two possibilities for $A$ up to isomorphism
> 3. if $k = \mathbb{F_p}$, there are three possibilities for $A$, up to isomorphism
> 4. if $k$ is algebraically closed, there are two possibilities for $A$, up to isomorphism

I know that number 1) is true, because we just need to choose $a$ and $b$ such that the roots of $(x^2+ax+b)$ is in $k$. Also, because $A$ is vector space with dimension $2$ over $k$, so there must be a unique $a$ and $b$ such that $(t^2+at+b) = 0$. In that case $k[x]/(x^2+ax+b) \cong A$. So in my opinion, there is only one possibility for $a$ and $b$, but it is not true. Can anyone give me some explanation for it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Say, if $k=\Bbb{Q}$ and $A=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ then the choices 1) $t=\sqrt2$, $x^2+ax+b=x^2-2$ and 2) $t=1+\sqrt2$, $x^2+ax+b=x^2-2x-1$ both give rise to the same (or isomorphic) $A$. To get infinitely many possibilities you need for example $t=\sqrt p$, $p$ some prime, $A=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt p)$. The point is that there are infinitely many non-isomorphic quadratic field extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$. OTOH if $x^2+ax+b$ has zeros in $\Bbb{Q}$ the only remaining question is whether it is a double root or not, only two non-isomorphic possibilities that way.

Comment: Elaborating a bit. If $x^2+ax+b=(x-t_1)(x-t_2)$ has two distinct roots $t_1$, $t_2\in\Bbb{Q}$. then, by Chinese Remainder Theorem, 
$$A=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+ax+b)\simeq \Bbb{Q}[x]/(x-t_1)\oplus\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x-t_2)\simeq \Bbb{Q}\oplus\Bbb{Q},$$ so all such choices lead to isomorphic $A$. OTOH $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^2)$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}\oplus\Bbb{Q}$. With an algebraically closed field in place of $\Bbb{Q}$ (so claim 4) these are the only possibilities, so $4$ is true. With finite fields there is only a single quadratic field extension implying that 3 is true, and 2 is false.

Comment: I won't write this as an answer, because I'm nearly 100% sure that we have handled this very question earlier.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JyrkiLahtonen, however, I don't quite get at 3). I guess, 3 possibility is from 3 types of polynomials: $x^2$, $(x - x_1)(x - x_2)$ and $(x^2 - t)$, here $t$ is not a square root of any element. Is it right?